# How to use Java Normalizer to convert a prebuilt string in Unicode to English read text

Tags: java, unicode, normalization, stringbuilder

I am trying to use Java to read a file, scan for Unicode as an escape sequence, convert to English readable, then write the replacement to the file.
As an example I make a similar script. The normalizer works if the input is a string, but if I build the string through an array or from a stringBuilder the output is literally the string without any normalization. How can I use a stringBuilder to work with Java's normalizer?

ex:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  String broke = "";
  String[] testArr = {"\\","u","0","0","e","0"};
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    broke+=testArr[i];
  }

    
    String works = "\u00e0";
    
      System.out.println("broke: " + broke);
        System.out.println("works: " + works);
    
    String temp = Normalizer.normalize(works, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        System.out.println("temp:" + temp);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    String fixedUnicode = pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("");
    System.out.println("fixedUnicode: " + fixedUnicode);
                    
  }
}
```

I notice Java automatically converts (String works = "\u00e0";) in a syso to the appropriate unicode, but a string that also looks like "\u00e0" but build with a stringBuilder or an array shows ("\u00e0") when using a syso

Comment: `\u1234` is parsed identically –by `javac`- as if you had typed in the character with that unicode codepoint. No method in java will 'parse' a literal sequence of backslash, u, 1, 2, 3, 4. However, you can trivially do something like `"foo" + (char) 0x1234 + "bar"` for the same effect, for example.

Comment: I believe the `Normalizer` class is for composing/decomposing characters with diacriticals (accents) or other adornments, not for escaping/unescaping. See [*Unicode Normalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) at Wikipedia.

Comment: *String[] testArr = {"\\","u","0","0","e","0"};* I don't get it. *Why* would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

As Basil Bourque said, Normalizer has *nothing* to do with Java Unicode escapes.  Do not attempt to use it for this;  it cannot do what you want at all.

First, let’s clarify something.  Writing this:

```
String s = "\u00e0";
```

is **exactly the same** as writing this:

```
String s = "à";
```

The compiler (not the Java runtime) will interpret any `\u` escape sequence as if it were the actual codepoint.  Regardless of which method is used for writing the string value, there is no `\` or `u` in the string.  At all.

However, if for some reason you have input that mistakenly added a literal backslash character, followed by a `u`, followed by four hex digits:

```
// This is NOT a Unicode escape.  It is a six-character string.
String s = "\\u00e0";
```

You can replace each such sequence using a regular expression [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
Matcher hexMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(\\p{XDigit}{4})").matcher(s);
String fixed = hexMatcher.replaceAll(
    r -> String.format("%c", Integer.valueOf(r.group(1), 16)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the breadcrumbs of VGR I was able to figure this one out. In production I am reading the string from a JSON file, converting every instance of "\u####" to an English looking letter. The automation software we use breaks with Unicode escape chars or accented letters.
I scan the document line by line and, if a "\u" is found a new string is created with the four following characters, creating a hex number.

ex:

```java
String hex = "####";
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
char myChar = (char) decimal;
String charConvert = myChar + "";

String tempie = Normalizer.normalize(charConvert, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
String fixedUnicode = pattern.matcher(tempie).replaceAll("");
```

From there I'm deleting the index in the line with index value of the "\u" found through index+6, then inserting the fixedUnicode string, walah.